# Unsecure cURL request in Java

Tags: java, curl

I have a line of code that I'm using in a shell script to send notifications to some users. I need to be able to use it in a Java application as well, but I am stuck on how to convert it to something Java would understand.

This is what the shell command looks like:

```
curl -u key:secret -d email=user@example.com \
--data-urlencode msg="test message" \
--data-urlencode url="http://www.airgramapp.com/welcome" \
https://api.airgramapp.com/1/send -k
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
URL url = new URL("curl -u key:secret -d email=user@example.com \
--data-urlencode msg="test message" \
--data-urlencode url="http://www.airgramapp.com/welcome" \
https://api.airgramapp.com/1/send -k");

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

Any help or guidance in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Couldn't you execute the shell script from Java using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);` See http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/ for an example.